# Find Number of different solution

Tags: permutations, combinations

Consider three integers a,b,c∈{1,2,3,4,5,6} and a+b+c=12. I am looking for the number of solutions for which none of the integers are repeated. For instance, the solution 1,5,6 is a valid combination, but 2,5,5 is not and (1,5,6),(1,6,5),(6,5,1),(6,1,5),(5,6,1),(5,1,6) are same. How many valid combinations are there? I know brute force(find all possible numbers and then check whether set of number is valid or not). But I want some formula.

Comment: You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/partition-function-without-duplicates if you are looking for a formula.

Comment: See this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294191/find-the-total-number-of-partitions-of-12-having-unequal-positive-parts).

Comment: @ N.F.Taussig I'm not a Mathematician. I don't understand it. What i understand is i don't need to change value of i from 1 to 4. P⋆(k,n)=P(k−(nC2),n). How this formula came.